# Getting tweets with React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, twitter, npm

I'm using the Twit package to pull tweets. I keep getting error 400, and

> Failed to load https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=twitterdev&count=10: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

The bulk of this was able to work with vanillajs, but once I imported into React, I've gotten these errors. How do I fix this? I've taken out the API keys for security.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Twit from 'twit';

export default class Twitter extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    const T = new Twit({
      consumer_key:         '...',
      consumer_secret:      '...',
      access_token:         '...',
      access_token_secret:  '...'
    })

    let params = {
      screen_name: 'twitterdev',
      count: 10
    };

    function getData(err, data, response) {
      let tweet = data;

      for (var i = 0; i<tweet.length; i++) { 
        console.log(tweet[i].text); 
        console.log();
       }
    }

    T.get('statuses/user_timeline', params, getData);
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div></div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Twitter API [does not](https://twittercommunity.com/t/will-twitter-api-support-cors-headers-soon/28276/1) support CORS requests. That's what you are trying to do. Accessing API from a different domain. You'll have to create a bespoke url at your local server that proxies the request to the Twitter
API.

Comment: How would I go about doing that? Do I have to host the project on a live server in order to test? I tried testing on 127.0.0.1:3000, and changing the website on apps.twitter to 127.0.0.1:3000 but that also didn't work.

Comment: You can still do it locally. I see that you’re using a local server. Are you controlling it.

Comment: well the app is running via react's boilerplate, by npm start

Comment: I see, so in this case you have to I guess use ‘yarn eject’ and mess with the code.